# Resize grips on borderless window with Monogame

Tags: c#, monogame, window-chrome

I'm trying to create a custom window UI that replaces the default window trimmings with a constant GUI across platforms by switching the main window to borderless and making custom logic for the dragging of the title bar, the buttons, and other functions. In WPF I would do this with the WindowChrome class (minus the cross-platform part) and I was wondering, is there was any method to get similar functionality in Monogame, specifically the resize grips on the edge of the borderless window?

Comment: I don't know the answer but have you considered just not allowing the user to resize the window? I've seen plenty of games that provide a way to change the window size in the options menu without giving complete resize freedom and it works quite well. I think Minecraft did this, and maybe FTL.

Comment: I would but the problem is I'm actually using Monogame to make a desktop app and I'm afraid that the user's expectation for that would be to have a resizable window rather than the hard-coded settings.

Comment: Yeah, fair enough. Sounds like an interesting project.